# Linear System of Differential Equations - Why can the coefficients be variable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $n$ variables $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ in a linear system of differential equations.

Suppose $\forall ~i : x_i' = f_i(t,x_1, \cdots, x_n)$

Now, if all the $f_i$'s are linear functionals, then we say that we have a linear system of differential equations.

If $f_i$ is a linear functional, then that means : $$ f_i(t,x_1, \cdots, x_n) = \lambda_0 t + \lambda_1x_1 + \cdots+\lambda_nx_n \cdots \cdots (1)$$

where $\lambda_i$ are real scalars.

But, my book specifically mentions a linear system of differential equation with respect to each $x_i$ as having the form :

$$x_i' = a_{i1}(t) x_1 + \cdots + a_{in}(t) x_n + b_i(t)$$

> My confusion here is how can the coefficients $a_{ij}$'s be a function of the independent variable $t$ here and contradict the definition of a linear functional as per $(1)$? Shouldn't they should be pure real constants to satisfy the definition of linearity?

> Secondly, we have a $b_i(t)$ in each line as well. How does that contribute to linearity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us be pragmatic: interesting ODE's are those such that a linear combination of solutions is also a solution.

If we consider

$$x'_i(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}(t)x_k(t)+b_i(t),$$

linearity fails, just for the fact that

$$(\lambda x_i)'(t)\ne \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}(t)(\lambda x_k)(t)+b_i(t).$$

But the homogeneous equation passes the linearity test:

$$(\lambda x_i+\mu y_i)'(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}(t)(\lambda x_k+\mu y_k)(t),$$ whether the coefficients depend on $t$ or not.

Hence it is legit to call *linear* such an equation, keeping in mind that this only holds for the homogeneous part of the solution. (A non-homogeneous equation might or should have been called *affine*, but there is a frequent confusion between linear and affine.)

Answer (score 2):

A linear functional and a linear differential equation are not the same thing. The two definitions do no contradict each other because nobody ever said that a linear differential equation must contain linear functionals.

I prefer to think about a linear differential equation as being linear **in all variables except $t$**.

Comment: Thanks. But then, we have a $b_i(t)$ in each line as well. How does that contribute to linearity?

Comment: @MathMan Again, it's part of linearity. I totally agree the phrasing is a little off here. But i guess the funciton $f(x)=kx + n$ is also called "linear", right? So it sorta makes sense. Sorta.